# How to read widgets from the .ui file in qt5?

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-designer

I am trying to get the list of widgets from a .ui files. 
So here is a bit of code:

```
    QUiLoader loader;
     QFile file(fname);
     file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
     QWidget *myWidget = loader.load(&file, this);
     file.close();

     QStringList avlb_wd = loader.availableWidgets();
     QMessageBox msg;

     foreach (const QString &str, avlb_wd)
     {
        msg.setText(str);
        msg.exec();
     }
```

But as I can see, availableWidgets() gives me all the widgets, not the ones that are in .ui file. 
How can I achieve it? 
Thanks forward.

Answer (score 2):

Make a subclass of `QUiLoader`, and reimplement [createWidget](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/quiloader.html#createWidget), [createLayout](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/quiloader.html#createLayout) and [createAction](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/quiloader.html#createAction) (there's also [createActionGroup](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/quiloader.html#createActionGroup), but it's not really supported any more, unless you manually edit the `ui` file).

These functions are called every time a new widget, layout or action is created by the ui loader. So just call the base-class implementation to get the created object, and then you can gather whatever information you like, before returning it.

**UPDATE**:

So the basic QUiLoader subclass would look like this (add other overloads as required):

```
class UiLoader : public QUiLoader
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   UiLoader(QObject *parent = 0) : QUiLoader(parent) { }

   virtual QWidget* createWidget(const QString &className,
   QWidget *parent = 0, const QString &name = QString())
   {
      QWidget* widget = QUiLoader::createWidget(className, parent, name);
      // do stuff with className, name, widget, etc
      return widget;
   }
};
```

Comment: Hi, I am quite new to Qt environment. Can you please show me how to make subclass and reimplement above functions? Or link me to docs where I can find info of how to do it? Some examples would really helpful. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @user3185491. I've added some code to get you started, but really, it's just very basic C++ stuff.